# Standardizing new Date().toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I am recording some user data using

```
const userTime = new Date().toLocaleString()
```

Sometimes the data returned looks like `7/2/2020, 4:58:46 PM`

Other times the data returned looks like `2/07/2020, 04:58:46`

I'm gonna be performing some analytics on this data so I'm gonna need a standardised format for consistency.

I prefer `7/2/2020, 4:58:46 PM`

How can I enforce the rules that I want when requesting the date and time?

Comment: see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Thanks bro, appreciate it!

Comment: I'm guessing this collects data from users world-wide.  Each has their own locale.  Either get, say, `.toJSON()`, or, `.toLocaleString('en-us')` or any other SPECIFIC language-locale.  I don't recommend "us" because it will WRONGLY put the month before the day... but I do recommend using "en" because some of your users might use other languages = deal with the problem before it arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use syntax like this:

```
  const date = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  })
```

If this answere was helpful mark it please. Thank you!

Comment: I got it working a little ago from reading the docs, thanks for posting though - I'm sure someone else might stumble on this answer